# TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable. How can I get this to remove an array from a 2d array?

Tags: python, arrays, typeerror

I have had a look at answers to similar questions but I just can't make this work. I am quite new to python.

```
def read():

    set = []
    f = open("error set 1.txt", "r")
    replace = f.read()
    f.close()

    f = open("Test1_Votes.txt", "w")
    replaced = replace.replace(",", "")
    f.write(replaced)
    f.close()



    f = open("Test1_Votes.txt", "r")
    for line in f:
        ballot = []


        for ch in line:

            vote = ch

            ballot.append(vote)

        print (ballot)

        set.append(ballot)


    """print(set)"""
    remove()

def remove():
    for i in range (70):
        x = i - 1
        check = set[x]
        if 1 not in check:
            set.remove[x]
    print(set)
```

The error is line 37, check = set[x]
I'm unsure of what is actually causing the error

Comment: "Subscript" means adding `[..]` to something. You can't use `[x]` on `set`. What do you expect that to do?

Comment: Avoid using `python` keywords such as `set` as variable names.

Answer (score 2):

In the `remove` function, you have not defined `set`. So, python thinks it's the built-in object `set`, which is actually not subscriptable.

Pass your object to the `remove` function, and, preferably, give it another name.

Answer (score 0):

Your remove function cant "see" your set variable (which is list, avoid using reserved words as variable name), because its not public, its defined only inside read function.
Define this variable before read function or send it as input to remove function, and it should be working.

```
def read():
    set = []
    f = open("error set 1.txt", "r")
    replace = f.read()
    f.close()

    f = open("Test1_Votes.txt", "w")
    replaced = replace.replace(",", "")
    f.write(replaced)
    f.close()

    f = open("Test1_Votes.txt", "r")
    for line in f:
        ballot = []


    for ch in line:
        vote = ch
        ballot.append(vote)

    print (ballot)

    set.append(ballot)


    """print(set)"""
    remove(set)

def remove(set):
    for i in range (70):
        x = i - 1
        check = set[x]
        if 1 not in check:
            set.remove(x)
    print(set)
```